# Problem with scrolling position (Nested Scroll View)

Tags: android, position, android-nestedscrollview

I am creating an app like "Duolingo". I have an activity that I want you to see:

[image]

A Constraint Layout can be seen which has the Image View with "Back" arrow, and with a Text View "Idiomas". Then you can see another text view (out of constraint) named "Opciones" and, below, a **brown line**. To finish, there is a frame-layout which is exchanging between fragments which (all) has recycler views inside. Those recyclers views has country flags as you can see in the image that I've attached.

**Problem:**

When I get into the activity, the scroll position (of nested scroll) is just below of the **brown line**. I'm attaching another photo of this situation:

[image]

I would like that when i get into the activity, the scroll position was into x:0 y:0 like you can see into photo *number 1*.

**Ive tried with this, but it just doesnt work (idk why)**

```
NestedScrollView nested = findViewById(R.id.nested);
nested_categorias.scrollTo(0,0);
```

**Im attaching my activity´s XML code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/nested"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.ui.INICIO.CATEGORIAS.categorias"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraint_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:background="#8d6e63"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_back_negro"
        android:tint="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_categoria"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        android:text="Idiomas"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15.5sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgbt_back"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgbt_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgbt_back" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_opciones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:text="@string/opciones"
    android:textColor="#795548"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint_bar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_barra1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#6d4c41"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_opciones" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_idiomas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_barra1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**What can I do to solve this?**